# Windows command line: findstr.exe cannot find a string in certain files when find find.exe finds it

Tags: windows, command-line, grep

My office computer is running Windows 7. It's very weird. I have ASCII files, containing String1. findstr.exe is able to find String1 only in certain files.
In many files String1 is not found by findstr. 
The command:

> findstr /i "String1" *

But, find.exe is able to  find String1 in all files, containing it.
The command:

> find /i "String1" *

All files have the same Windows/DOS EOL \r\n (EOL doesn't matter, but anyway)
Permissions look the same.
Is there any idea why findstr.exe is not able to find?

Comment: It's nothing to do with `grep`, which is a commandline tool from unix system, but you can try it, you can download GNU grep for windows. It's much better than findstr.

Comment: It might because of Encoding of the files, check the difference.

Comment: Yes, It is encoding. I found the difference. find.exe looks more reliable. Thanks!